# facebook lead details retrieval from lead gen id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am unable to get lead details from lead gen id that gets generated using webhook. Although I have admin access and lead retrieval access I get the following message when tried to access lead details from lead gen id

"message": "(#200) Requires leads retrieval permission to manage the object", "type": "OAuthException",

Comment: Which type of token are you using, and do you fulfill _all_ the requirements the documentation mentions?

Comment: Do we need to have lead access approval from facebook after publishing the app?

Comment: Of course you do.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's useful, I had the same problem.
The api must be active and published in addition to revised with approval.

Then access a new version of the Graph API browser
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?classic=0

must give the correct permissions to the Token
Permissions = leads_retrieval

a greeting